# Understanding the term "Abstraction" in mathematics

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis

When the need for abstraction is asserted in mathematics is it generally meant that there is a need to apply a definition to n-dimensions such that n is an integer going to infinity?

Comment: No, that's not generally what it means. There are abstract parts of mathematics that have nothing to do with dimensions, integers, or infinity.

Comment: If you have a definition of a certain object which holds for a certain dimension (for example dimension $2$ or $3$), extending that definition to dimension $n$ is usually called "generalization to dimension $n$". I don't know if a definition of "abstraction" exists.

Comment: I would say abstraction does loosely mean generalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstraction in mathematics is usually the process of taking a familiar concept, selecting several properties of the concept you deem important, and then exploring all things that have those properties. The common theme is beginning with something familiar, and then asking about everything else that is "like" the object you are familiar with.

By focusing only on a specific set of properties, you can concentrate on exactly what follows from those properties, and other features, which had perhaps distracted you in the specific example, are cast aside.

For instance, the integers are a nonempty set which you can add, subtract and multiply in, and also the distributive property holds. The abstraction of those properties is called a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)).

Another example is this: "squares and triangles are finite strings of line segments in a plane which make a path that doesn't cross itself." Abstracting this, you would get the concept of [simple polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon).

In $\Bbb R^n$ you can add, subtract and scale vectors using the field $\Bbb R$, and addition and scaling distribute over each other. By replacing $\Bbb R$ with other fields $F$, and exploring other sets $V$ with the same properties allows us to abstract to [vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).

Comment: It's worth noting that even if you are interested in a *specific* mathematical object, abstraction can still make it much easier to work with that mathematical object, by focusing on the properties of the object that are important and hiding the details that are not.

Comment: Thank you that set me straight. This explanation has helped a lot. It also explains the desire I had to frame my OP in different terms. I wanted to see what would happen if I just kept the question as base as possible. I've absorbed the term abstraction in the context of art and philolosphy which lead to my initial confusion.